# How to find 6 digits in a string with a particular pattern on the first 3 digits in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to find a regular expression to return to me the entire 6 digits with the first 3 digits as a pattern/fixed.

Ex:

```
import re
string_ex = 'docs/data/622999/2013904065003_file.bin'

re.findall(r'622(\d{3})',string_ex)
```

results in just `['999']` 
but I want the result to be `['622999']`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should include `622` too within the parenthesis

```
>>> import re
>>> string_ex = 'docs/data/622999/2013904065003_file.bin'
>>> re.findall(r'(622\d{3})',string_ex)
['622999']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "index" on the string directly.

```
i = string_ex.index("622")
found = string_ex[i-3:i+2]
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm